# google real-time multiplayer api example: ButtonClicker

Tags: android, real-time, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

i have been really wanting to create a real-time multiplayer android game and was following this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

I even corrected the errors on the ButtonClicker example(it's the only one with real-time multiplayer) and got it to work, but didn´t test the multiplayer yet. I copied the whole project to my brother´s computer and he tried to play with me. But every time he click on the button to invite me, it´s saying "the project is incorrectly configured". Does he have to generate another aplication id? has anyone tested the example using 2 different computers and the android emulator of eclipse?

Comment: Maybe you want to revisit some of your earlier questions, they seem to be abandoned by you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services aren't typically installed on the emulator. I think you'll need a pair of actual devices.

It might also need signed applications, but I'm not that familiar (yet) with the Google Play Services model.

Comment: are u sure i can only test it on actual device? Is this the reason for the problem? I already signed this example app on my google play developer console: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?dev_acc=08731734841071974476#GameListPlace

Answer (score 1):

I think i resolved it(at least my brother could login on his computer) by adding testers to my project on google play development console. Now all he needs to do is use another emulator on his computer to emulate multiplayer, just like i did ^^

Answer (score 0):

if its giving you an unconfigured error, double check that you signed your app with the same certificate as the sha1 that you linked.